# Eliminar elementos previamente creados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un formulario el cual al recibir una petición por medio de Ajax, y depende de la opción que elija el usuario (estas opciones vienen por medio de un `select`), almacene sus valores en un `div`.

- *HTML:*

```html
 <select class="custom-select" id="lista" name="lista">
    <option selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>
    <option value="1">Opcion #1</option>
    <option value="2">Opcion #2</option>
</select>
```

- *Javascript:*

```
    $("#lista").change(function(){
        var lista = $("#lista").val();
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("lista", lista); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "....",
            method:"POST",
            data: datos,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: window.respuesta
        });
    });
```

- *Función respuesta donde se crean los div:*

```
function respuesta(respuesta){
    let fila = $(".f-indicadores");

    for(let i = 0; i < respuesta.length; ++i)
    {
        fila.append('<div class="col-12"><p>' + respuesta[i].BANCO + '</p></div>');
    }
}
```

Dichos `div` se crean mediante el metodo `append` como se ve arriba y se almacenan aqui:

```
<div class="row f-indicadores">
   <div class="col-12" id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Pero luego al crearse, y solicitar otra petición (es decir, el usuario elige otra opción en el select), vuelve a crear otros `div` por encima de los ya creados anteriormente.

Mi duda es, ¿como seria posible eliminar los `div` previamente creados?.

Comment: Puedes revisar mi respuesta que te acabo de dejar más abajo. Si es de tu utilidad la puedes marcar para que pueda ayudar a otros a futuro que presenten el mismo problema o requieran hacer algo similar. Saludos !.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function respuesta(respuesta){
    let fila = $(".f-indicadores"); //selecciona la fila
    fila.text(" "); // el metodo text() eliminas los divs interno

    for(let i = 0; i < respuesta.length; ++i){
        fila.append('<div class="col-12"><p>' + respuesta[i].BANCO + '</p></div>');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row f-indicadores">
   <div class="col-12" id="content">holas</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas cambiar `append()` por `html()` asi:

```
function respuesta(respuesta){
let fila = $(".f-indicadores");
let divs = "";

for(let i = 0; i < respuesta.length; ++i)
{
    divs += '<div class="col-12"><p>' + respuesta[i].BANCO + '</p></div>';
}
fila.html(divs);
}
```

Comment: Al aplicar `.html`, como esta dentro de un ciclo, solo añade el ultimo elemento, a cambio con el `.append` añade todo los elementos

Comment: Tienes razon, ya edite mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder eliminar o remover un elemento `HTML` podrías usar el método de `removeChild()` el cual elimina un nodo hijo del `DOM` y puede devolver el `nodo`.

Te dejo un ejemplo básico de su funcionamiento, podrías adecuarlo a tus necesidades y si necesitas saber más acerca de este método un buen sitio es la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) que puedes revisar.

```js
function handleRemoveElement () {
  var top = document.getElementById("top");
  var nested = document.getElementById("nested");
  var garbage = top.removeChild(nested);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top" align="center"> 
    PADRE
    <div id="nested">HIJO (me van a eliminar)</div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="handleRemoveElement()">Remove Element</button>
</body>
</html>
```